# Clearing a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Would appreciate any help from anyone... the below PHP contains a list of items from a txt file, next to each item is a text box for the user to enter the qty, by default set to 1. I'm trying to clear the box when the user clicks on a text box, any ideas?

```
<input type='text' id='qty' name='$partno' size='1' value='0'>
```

So far I've tried using JavaScript but had no luck.

```
        <script>
        function validateName()
        {
            var x=document.forms["purchase"]["visitor"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert("Visitor name must be entered");
                return false;
            }
        }

        function name()
        {  
            document.getElementById('qty').value = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Items Available</h1>

    <form id="purchase" name="purchase" action="confirm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateName()">
        <table>

            <h3>Visitor Name: <input type='text' name='visitor'></h3>
            <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Price</th><th>QTY</th></tr>

            <?php
            if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
                echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
                exit;
            }
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {

                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                echo "<tr><td><img src='$image' width='60' height='60' alt='image'></td><td><h3>$name</h3></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$description</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&pound;$price</b></td><td><input type='text' id='qty' name='$partno' size='1' value='0'></td></tr>";
                //<input type='text' size='1' name='partno_qty' value='1'</td>
            }
            ?> 

        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Purchase">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">

    </form>
```

Comment: The PHP for this is rather irrelevant to the question; I think it'd be helpful if you just posted the resulting HTML without the PHP for better readability.

Comment: In addition, you setting identical id attributes in a for loop, resulting in duplicate ids on the same page. An ID can only occur once within an HTML document; it needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Add an onclick or onfocus handler to your "input name=qty" tag, or look at using a "placeholder" attribute, which may not work in some browsers you have to support:

```
foreach ($data as $thedata)
{
    list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                echo '<tr><td><img src="' . $image . '" width="60" height="60" alt="image"></td>'
                . '<td><h3>' . $name . '</h3></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $description . '</td>'
                . '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&pound;' . $price . '</b></td>'
                . '<td><input type="text" id="part-' . $partno . '" '
                . 'name="' . $partno . '" size="1" '
                . 'value="0" onfocus="this.value=\'\';" placeholder="0"></td>'
                . '</tr>';
}
```

The "onclick/onfocus" approach will clear the box every time it's clicked/entered. If you wish to use your "name" function, the call changes to this:

```
onfocus="name( this );"
```

And "name" changes to:

```
function name( obj )
{  
    obj.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Might be better to use onFocus so that it works if the user tabs to the field

Comment: I can't since the name is a variable.

Comment: Sure you can.  If you must call a function to perform the action, you can _always_ pass "this" to it, which is a reference to the object receiving the event.

Comment: I problem is the txt box is within PHP so the onfocus syntax doesn't comply.

Comment: The "name" function you defined is not in PHP, it's in JavaScript.  Passing "this" to an onfocus event handler will work, and it's completely separate from PHP. I editied my answer above to create unique IDs for your text boxes, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 `placeholder` and `required` attributes:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/kJMk8/)

**Notes:** 
The `placeholder` attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.
The `required` tag is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome. It's not supported in Safari

or you can do it in JS like this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="inputFocus(this, 'initial text')" onblur="inputBlur(this, 'initial text')" value="initial text" />
```

`'initial text'` is the default value of the text input when page loads e.g.('Your Name').

```
function inputFocus(elm, placeholder){
    if (elm.value == placeholder){ elm.value = "" }

}

function inputBlur(elm, placeholder){
    if (elm.value == "" || elm.value == placeholder){
        elm.style.border = "1px solid red";
        elm.value = placeholder;
        alert("Visitor name must be entered");
    }else{
        elm.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/vKJEy/)